# Alfresco : External Webservice calling gettting error not able to get result?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

Alfresco community edition-5.1.x. when calling external webservice I'm getting error not able to get result

Code:

```
function updateList(){
    Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({

                url: "http://test.com/webservice/mgmobile/mgserver.php?wsfunction=course_get_all_courses&wstoken=7f5e0f05f7c54ece7a23f02fe3718464",
        method: Alfresco.util.Ajax.GET,

                headers: ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'),
                headers: ('Access-Control-Request-Headers: *'),
                headers: ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *'),
        requestContentType: Alfresco.util.Ajax.JSON,
        successCallback:{
            fn: function(res){  
                appendOptiOnvalues(res)
            },
        },
        failureCallback:{
            fn: function(res){  
                alert("Error");
            },
        }
    });

}
```

Error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://test.com/webservice/mgmobile/mgserver.php?wsfunction=course_get_all_courses&wstoken=7f5e0f05f7c54ece7a23f02fe3718464. (Reason: missing token 'content-type' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

Please help on this.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/jottley/cors-enable-alfresco-for-cors. Can you please take a quick look on this ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the call is being made to a non-Alfresco server so configuring CORS on Alfresco is not going to help. Instead, check the CORS configuration on the server you are calling and make sure that it is setting "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" to allow the "content-type" header to be specified. That's probably being set by the Alfresco AJAX util library you are using.

I don't know what server you are calling, so I can't provide CORS help specific to that server, but [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) is some info on enabling CORS for various types of servers.

Answer (score 0):

We came across this today when trying to call an Alfresco Webscript from the Alfresco Share UI and found the issue was in the Alfresco Platform CORS configuration. Our `Alfresco.util.Ajax.request` included the following headers with the request by default:

- localtoken
- x-requested-with

These had to be included in our `cors.allowed.headers` property in `alfresco-global.properties` otherwise the request would be rejected with an HTTP 403 by ACS.

**Example**

```
cors.enabled=true
cors.allowed.origins=http://localhost:8180
cors.allowed.methods=GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
cors.allowed.headers=origin, authorization, x-file-size, x-file-name, content-type, accept, x-file-type, range, localtoken, x-requested-with
cors.support.credentials=true
cors.exposed.headers=Accept-Ranges, Content-Encoding, Content-Length, Content-Range, content-type, localtoken
```

**Notes**
Keep in mind `alfresco-global.properties` is where you configure this when using the ACS all-in-one-platform-docker container provided by Alfresco. If deploying your own WAR in Tomcat or another application server you'll need to follow instructions specific to that system.